# Process only tiled event and not maximize event

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I'm building a very basic calculator program using GTKMM

[Basic Calculator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZoos.png)

The layout is in landscape mode (buttons and display label in **horizontal** orientation) by design

I want to orient those two to portrait mode (ie., in **vertical**) when the user snaps/tiles the window to the right or left

Below is a sample code I used:

```cpp
bool
BasicCalculator::on_calculator_window_state_changed(
        GdkEventWindowState     *window_state_event,
            Gtk::Box            *box)
{
        if (
                window_state_event->new_window_state &
                (Gdk::WINDOW_STATE_RIGHT_TILED | Gdk::WINDOW_STATE_LEFT_TILED)
        )
                box->set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
        else
                box->set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
        return true;
}
```

- [Window tiled left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lur7p.png) and [right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYNDr.png)
- [Window maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0zw7.png)

The code works but my window orients vertically when maximized which is not my intention. I want it to be in horizontal orientation

How do I process only the tiled event and not the maximize event?

PS: [My project repo](https://gitlab.com/Keyikedalube/basic-calc) in case you want to build & test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hacking around a bit with the `GdkEventWindowState` enums, I figured I can compare against the tiled state with the window maximized state together

ie., make sure to switch orientation to vertical only if the window is tiled and not maximized

Because the code

```cpp
...
        if (
                window_state_event->new_window_state &
                (Gdk::WINDOW_STATE_RIGHT_TILED | Gdk::WINDOW_STATE_LEFT_TILED)
        )
                ...
```

returns TRUE not just for the tiled state but also for maximized state also

Below is the improved code that works:

```cpp
bool
BasicCalculator::on_calculator_window_state_changed(
        GdkEventWindowState     *window_state_event,
            Gtk::Box            *box)
{
        bool is_window_tiled = window_state_event->new_window_state &
                        (Gdk::WINDOW_STATE_RIGHT_TILED | Gdk::WINDOW_STATE_LEFT_TILED);
        bool is_window_maximized = window_state_event->new_window_state &
                        Gdk::WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED;

        if (is_window_tiled && !is_window_maximized)
                box->set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
        else
                box->set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);

        return true;
}
```

Now the window keeps its default horizontal orientation even if maximized :)